# I cannot get a repeating table with a repeating drop down to show answers previously selected from MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table with the table headings below.  Each row of that table populates info from a database.  One of those columns (category) is a drop down menu (with a LOT of entries), so I've used a separate table to pull the values from.  When a user submits the page with the drop down value selected, I want them to see the value they chose last time, as they may have to come back to this form multiple times.  If you look at where the var_dump is, I can see that it's pulling the previously selected values from the database, but when I try to use the very same $row["category"] entry in the selected = $row["category"] I get the first entry in the drop down list, NOT the selected value (which was again verified as existing with the var_dump). I have no idea why this is happening and have spent DAYS trying to figure this out before asking the community here. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
        <th scope="col">Date</th> 
        <th scope="col">Amount</a></th>
        <th scope="col">Vendor</th>
        <th scope="col">Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Category</th>
        <th scope="col">Notes</th>
        <th scope="col">Bind Values?</th>
        <th scope="col">Trip</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Updated</th>
        <th scope="col">Updated By</th>
        <th scope="col">Done</th>
  </tr>

<?php

$category_query = "SELECT * FROM category order by category_name ASC";
$category_result = mysqli_query($connection, $category_query);

$category_options = NULL;

while ($category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($category_result)) {
    $category_options .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>".PHP_EOL, $category["category_name"], $category["category_name"]);


}

?>

<form action="process_table.php" method="post">



<?php

$transactions_query = "SELECT transactions_id, `date`, amount, vendor, description, category , trip, last_updated, last_updated_by, done, notes\n"
    . "FROM users, transactions\n"
    . "WHERE users.user_name = '{$_SESSION["user"]}' AND users.users_id = transactions.users_id";


$transactions_result = mysqli_query($connection, $transactions_query);




while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($transactions_result)) { 
$id = $row["transactions_id"];

var_dump($row["category"]);
?>




 <tr>
 <td><?php echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($row["date"]));?></td>
 <td><?php echo number_format($row["amount"], 2);?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row["vendor"];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row["description"];?></td>


 <td>  <?php 

 if ($row["done"] == "checked") {
    echo '<select selected ="'.$row["category"].'"  name="expense['.$id.'][category]">'.$category_options.'</select>';  
 } else {
echo "DUMB"/*'<select name="expense['.$id.'][category]">'.$category_options.'</select>'*/;  
 }
 ?>

</td>


 <td><?php echo "<textarea name='expense[" . $id . "][notes]'>" . $row["notes"] . "</textarea>";?></td>

 <td><input name="bind" type="checkbox" value="YES"></td>

 <td nowrap="nowrap">Trip place holder</td>

 <td><?php echo date("m/d/Y")?></td>
     <td>
     <?php 
        if (!isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
            echo "temp" ;
        } else {
          echo  $_SESSION["user"];
        }

     ?>
     </td>


 <td><?php echo "<input name='expense[" . $id . "][done]' type='checkbox'"?> <?php  if($row["done"] == "checked") {
     echo "checked = 'checked'>";
 } else {
        echo ">"; 
 }

 ?>

  </td>

 </tr>




<?php
}
?>





</table>





<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" >
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a option as selected, you need to apply the attribute `selected="selected"` to the `<option>` not the `<select>` element - The attribute as you currently have it will just be ignored, where most browsers will default to the first item in the list.

Change this:

```
<select selected ="'.$row["category"].'"
```

To this:

```
<select name="name">
 <option value="option1">Value 1</option>
 <option value="option2" selected="selected">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

In the above example the `option2` option will be selected.

(**edit**) Using your own code:

```
<select name="<?php echo sprintf('expense[%s][%s]', $id, $category); ?>">
  <option value="">Please select&hellip;</option>
  <?php
    foreach($category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($category_result)) :
      if ($row["category"] == $category['category_name']) {
        echo '<option value="'. $category['category_name'] .'" selected="selected">'. $category['category_name'] . "</option>";
      } else {
        echo '<option value="'. $category['category_name'] .'">'. $category['category_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    endforeach;
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Alex, REALLY appreciate the help.  I can't believe I made such a foolish mistake.  Far more familiar with PHP than I am with HTML, as crazy as that sounds.  I will try the code you've provided now.

Comment: Alex, where would I insert this code or what would I replace it with?

Comment: @user2643898 The last block of code is building your category select element. You should be able to see it creates the first `<select>` and then loops over the `$category_result` - while looping we check if the current category name is equal to the previously selected `$row["category"] == $category['category_name']` if it is then we show a option with the `selected="selected"` and if not the same option without one.